# Adding a Json Object after a particular Object in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an array of objects which looks like

```
arr = [
    {"className":"section", "name":"input"},
    {"className":"col", "name":"dropdown"},
    {"className":"section", "name":"table"}
]
```

Now I want to push an object `{"fieldName":"new"}` after every object which has `"className":"section"`

So my final output should look like something like this

```
arr = [
    {"className":"section", "name":"input"},
    {"fieldName":"new"},
    {"className":"col","name":"dropdown"},
    {"className":"section", "name":"table"},
    {"fieldName":"new"}]
```

How do I acheive this in Javascript?

Comment: Do you have to push these into the same array? It's easier if you create a new array.

Comment: There's no [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) in your question -> [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array.reduce`.

```js
let arr = [{"className":"section", "name":"input"},{"className":"col", "name":"dropdown"},{"className":"section", "name":"table"}];

arr = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc.push(item);
    if (item.className === "section") {
        acc.push({ fieldName: "new" });
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
arr.forEach(obj => {
 if (obj.className === 'section') {
  const index = arr.indexOf(obj)
  arr.splice(index, 0, 
  {"fieldName":"new"} )
 }
})
```